# DAX DIVIDE and / operator not returning the same result

Tags: dax, ssas-tabular

We have a report connected, via a live connection, to an analysis services tabular model.

We have this measure:

```
MeasureX=
VAR NumLogins =
    CALCULATE (
        [Measure Dynamic Agg],
        'Time Periods'[PeriodCalc] = "Current MtD",
        'Calendar'[Is Current Month] = "TRUE",
        'Measures - Financial Agg'[Formula] = "Num Logins",
        ALL ( 'Measures - Financial'[Formula] )
    )
VAR NumCategories =
    CALCULATE (
        [Measure Dynamic],
        'Time Periods'[PeriodCalc] = "Current MtD",
        'Calendar'[Is Current Month] = "TRUE",
        'Measures - Financial'[Formula] = "Num Categories",
        ALL ( 'Measures - Financial Agg'[Formula] )
    )
RETURN
DIVIDE(NumLogins ,NumCategories)
```

In the dashboard this returns blanks everywhere.

If we change the last line of DAX to the following it returns numbers as expected:

```
...
...
RETURN
NumLogins / NumCategories
```

Does anyone have any clue what is happening? I was under the impression that semantically using the / operator and DIVIDE function were the same, apart from handling divide by zero differently?

Answer (score 0):

DIVIDE handles both zeroes **and blanks** in the denominator. It's the blanks that are getting you here. Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/best-practices/dax-divide-function-operator.

Comment: cheers for answer. if I alter the `RETURN` to just `RETURN NumCategories` there are no blanks or zeros, just numbers

Comment: Depending on the context blanks can be suppressed in reports.

Comment: I'm using the AS Measure in the same context as the report level measure - they are the same - the AS measure works only using `/` but the report level measure works with either `DIVIDE` or `/`. So context is not the reason

Comment: I could play with it further if you add sample data to your question.